# How to get option set rules in Bigcommerce

Tags: rules, bigcommerce

I want to create or update a Products using Option sets through API. When i adding the rules for Option set in Big commerce Site, how do get these option set rules through API?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help with this? Its there any way to get option set rules from an external application?

Comment: @tomekole, did you find the way to get rules for option sets? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not a way to access option set rules through the API with Bigcommerce. However, you can simply run a script that gets each product with that option set applied to it and then iterate through those products to set the same rules on each one!