# Get option set rules from Bigcommerec api

Tags: bigcommerce

I am able to get the product rules using :

```
$product_url = $url.'/api/v2/products/'.$productID.'/rules.json';
```

I have now added some rules on the optionset and cannot see how to get those through the api.

MrWarby

PS this is a duplicate of [How to get option set rules in Bigcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283454/how-to-get-option-set-rules-in-bigcommerce) but I could not comment on this to renew it.

What is the correct procedure in this case?

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help with this? Its there any way to get option set rules from an external application?